# supervisorctl without using Sqs which i get error on that

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord

After install and configure `supervisor` i have some jobs and queue on `Laravel` web application, my server os is `centOs` and after run `supervisor` i get this error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'Aws\Sqs\SqsClient' not found
```

I dont use Amazon server and i dont install this package on laravel, i'm trying to run `queue:work` command to listen jobs and queues. my configuration:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
command=php /home/myApp/artisan queue:work redis --timeout=120 --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
;user=forge
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/myApp/worker.log
```

and `queue` config:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'redis'),
```

how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: You should post your database config (this is where redis is set up), and a more detailed queue config

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you want to use Redis as your queue provider, in that case make sure that the `.env` file in your server doesn't have `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sqs`

if you want to use Redis, it should be `QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis`